# Como baixar PDF com a url no sdcard? Android

Tags: java, android, url, pdf

Eu gostaria de poder fazer um botão que quando clicado, baixasse um pdf com a url deste para o sdcard, mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum...

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a classe `DownloadManager` do próprio Android. Ela já irá fazer todo o trabalho para você (incluindo as notificações com progresso e de sucesso/falha):

```
String url = "http://suaurl.com.br/";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDescription("Alguma descrição");
request.setTitle("Algum titulo");

//A notificação de conslusão só esta disponível a partir da API 11
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
}

//Salvando o arquivo no diretório de Downloads
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "MeuPdf.pdf");

DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

O resultado ficará assim:

[image: Fazendo o download do arquivo]

E, quando completo:

[image: Download completo]

Você poderá visualizar o arquivo na pasta `Downloads`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O AP deveria aceitar sua resposta, precisei fazer isso e usei sua resposta como base :)